# Reload label swift 3 core data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I have an xCode project and I want to reload a label which contain the user score,

here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var moneyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageMoneyMove: UIImageView!
var managedObjextContext:NSManagedObjectContext!

var coreDataMoney = [Money] ()
var money:Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    managedObjextContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    loadData()

    let moneyItem = Money(context: managedObjextContext)
    moneyLabel.text! = String(moneyItem.allMoney)

}
func loadData() {
    let presentRequest:NSFetchRequest<Money> = Money.fetchRequest()
do {
        coreDataMoney = try managedObjextContext.fetch(presentRequest)
} catch {
        print("Could not load data from database \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

@IBAction func addMoney(_ sender: Any) {

    let moneyItem = Money(context: managedObjextContext)
    money += 1
    moneyItem.allMoney = Float(money)

    moneyLabel.text! = String(moneyItem.allMoney)

    print(moneyItem.allMoney)

    do {
        try self.managedObjextContext.save()
        self.loadData()
    }catch {
        print("Could not save data \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    print(moneyItem.allMoney)
}`
```

I have an Entity called Money and an attribute of type Float and named allMoney. Thank you !

Comment: I would like that when application launches, my score appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an Entity `Money` with is supposed to contain a single record I recommend to implement a computed property with custom getter and setter.

I renamed `coreDataMoney` with `money` and `money` with `amount`

- First of all declare variable for the `Money` object and a lazy instantiated variable for the managed object context.

  ```
  var money : Money!

  lazy var managedObjextContext : NSManagedObjectContext = {
      return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
  }()
  ```
- Declare the variable `amount`.

  - The `get`ter checks if the variable `money` containing the `NSManagedObject` is `nil`. If yes, the object is loaded, then the value is returned.
  - The `set`ter updates the value in the `NSManagedObject` object, saves the context and updates the label.

    ```
    var amount : Float {
        get {
            if money == nil {
                loadData()
            }
            return money.allMoney
        }
        set {
            money.allMoney = newValue
            saveContext()
            moneyLabel.text! = String(newValue)
        }
    }
    ```
- Create a convenience method to save the context.

  ```
  func saveContext() {
      do {
          try self.managedObjextContext.save()
      } catch {
          print("Could not save data \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
  }
  ```
- The `loadData()` method load the `Money` object. If the entity is empty create one.

  ```
  func loadData() {
      let presentRequest:NSFetchRequest<Money> = Money.fetchRequest()
      do {
          let coreDataMoney = try managedObjextContext.fetch(presentRequest)
          if coreDataMoney.isEmpty {
              let moneyItem = Money(context: managedObjextContext)
              money = moneyItem
              saveContext()
          } else {
              money = coreDataMoney.first!
          }
      } catch {
          print("Could not load data from database \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
  }
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad` get the variable `amount` to load the data and update the label.

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       moneyLabel.text! = String(amount)
  }
  ```
- Finally in the `addMoney` method just increment the `amount` property. The setter logic updates the CoreData stack and the label.

  ```
  @IBAction func addMoney(_ sender: Any) {
      amount += 1.0
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, but I have 2 errors: the first one in the first line of the declaration of the variable amount which says Cannot call value of non-function type 'Double', and th second one on the moneyLabel.text = String(amount) which says variable used within its own initial value. Thank you again